# How to transpose EG5.1

Tags: sas, transpose, enterprise-guide

I have a data set of approximately this format:

Table format :

| ID | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |  |
| B | 2 |  | 4 |

And I want to transpose it to this format:

Table format :

| ID | Source | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2012 | 1 |
| A | 2013 | 3 |
| B | 2012 | 2 |
| B | 2014 | 4 |

Using the Transpose task. I'm working in EG 5.1 and I've got a massive mental block on how to do this. Most of the guides are for doing this the opposite way around. Thanks so much in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `proc transpose` instead. Create a new SAS program and run the following code:

```
proc transpose data = have
               out  = want(rename = (COL1 = Value)  
                           where  = (NOT missing(Value) )
                          )
               name = Source;
    by id;
    var _NUMERIC_;
run;
```

Output:

```
ID  Source  Value
A   2012    1
A   2013    3
B   2012    2
B   2014    4
```

In Enterprise Guide, this is the Stack Columns task:

[image]